# hcitool lescan returning error

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3

I'm running BlueZ 5.41 on a RPi 3 and I'm getting this error. up/down/reset don't do anything to help nor does a power cycle.

```
    pi@RPiTester:~/ble-stuff $ hciconfig
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: UART
        BD Address: B8:27:EB:F0:83:F1  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
        UP RUNNING PSCAN
        RX bytes:8883 acl:40 sco:0 events:634 errors:0
        TX bytes:7685 acl:43 sco:0 commands:488 errors:0

pi@RPiTester:~/ble-stuff $ sudo /home/pi/bluez/bluez-5.41/tools/hcitool lescan
Set scan parameters failed: Input/output error
pi@RPiTester:~/ble-stuff $
```

Where do I start to try and debug this? One odd thing I noticed is that the hci0 device is on the UART bus and not the dbus. Is that normal for RPi BT?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, executing the following command made hcitool work again:

```
bluetoothctl
```

After restarting the machine the error appears sometimes again.

There are some notes about Raspberry Pi 3 and UART: 
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571